# What are Cloud Computing Applications?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, cloud

So I've been studying Cloud Computing lately and I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept, since my background is mostly front-end web development.

I've gone over most of the Service Models and abstract computing services, but I still don't see the bigger picture I guess.

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is a Cloud Application. **Is it just a website hosted by a huge datacenter? Can I only access Cloud Application through a web browser then? And is it possible to have a desktop application 'running' in the cloud? If so, what kind of code is running in the cloud?**

I just can't seem to find clear explanations on those questions.

I guess it's all still foggy to me, so I hope anyone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud use service model : IaaS (Infrastructure as a service)  , PaaS(Platform as a service) , SaaS (Software as a service ).

Simple example that use cloud is : Microsoft Azure , Amazon's Ec2 , google drive

Cloud is only application that provide user infrastructure , platform or software online with user-defined requirement and is scalable . that is maintained and upgraded by cloud provider.

user have to pay only for what they are using.

Your Answers :

--> Is it just a website hosted by a huge datacenter? 
A. No , it is not website. it is service that enable user to store data , work with software online.

--> Can I only access Cloud Application through a web browser then? 
A. Most probably you can use through web browser.

--> Is it possible to have a desktop application 'running' in the cloud? If so, what kind of code is running in the cloud?
A. Yes , the applications that run on cloud also contain desktop application. E.g , word editor or photo editor is desktop application and if you need for your cloud that then cloud provider provide you that application for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at the different [service models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Service_models) that you could have on the cloud. Specially, I would read carefully the Infrastructure as a service (IaaS) and Platform as a service (PaaS) concepts.

Briefely, when you have your application and you would like to deploy it on the cloud you should choose between different models.

Iaas. Where you have an Infrastructure as a Service. It means that you a re renting a physical machine in a specific datacenter that you can choose. You have the possibility to install several Operative System where you can start installing, for example, your Tomcat Java container, your MySQL database. Please, note that you don't need any infrastructure on your end but you still need to install/configure/maintain all the software. This is the Amazon EC2 model.

PaaS. They provide a service on the top of an IaaS where you are renting an infrastructure but you have also a lot of services preconfigured so you DON'T need to install Tomcat, MySQL,.. You have Tomcat as a Service, MySQL as a Service, PostgreSQL as a Service. With this model you don't to install anything, you have your application and you just deploy your app on the container that you would like. You can take a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKGXff0jjWw) which shows you on a graphical way how to deploy your application on a PaaS so you can see the differencen with an IaaS.